# Playing with Referrer Header

Tags: php, javascript, web-applications, web-scraping

There are 2 sites:

```
http://www.site1.com
http://www.site2.com
```

`http://www.site1.com` contains link to `http://www.site2.com` as

```
<a href="http://www.site2.com/">link<a/>
```

When user clicks on link from `http://www.site1.com` browser sends Referrer header to `http://www.site2.com`. Based on Referrer header `http://www.site2.com` makes some processes.

I wonder if I can fake/change (maybe with javascript, PHP, ...) Referrer header or not send it at all?

Answer (score 0):

You normally should not be able change the Referer header yourself (maybe using only browser bugs, which, however, are likely to be fixed in a short time), however, you may wish to use or make a dereferrer site, which basically changes the referrer to it's URL. example: http://dereferer.org/start.asp.